# Crystal Reports report 02.months - 01.next months

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

in Crystal Report 13 generated reports , the report is divided into months , with the first on the first number , and grouped automatically. It is necessary that the report formed the second day of the first month and the first day of the next . That is: with 05.02.2016 on 06.01.2016 how to implement it manually , I found a group , but the problem is that I have to create each month itself, and how to implement it in the formula can not understand . Sorry for my english , Google translator , as the Russian forums did not find help.

Now it looks like this:
[image]

and should
[image]

Дата this DateTime

Comment: Can you show with sample data and report structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of hardwork, I was able to find a solution.. try and let me know if it works. Its a tested solution though.

This can be done using the sub report.

Create a formula `Required date` and write below code:

```
CDate(DateAdd("d",1,CDate(Year({Дата}),Month({Дата}),01)))
```

In main report create a group using the created formula `Required date` and  unless you want some sections to display in main report suppress all sections except `group footer`

Now create a sub report with same tables as main report and place the report in group footer 1, Now link the created formula to the sub report, In sub report there will be a paramter created as `Pm-@Required date`

Open sub report `Record Selection Formula` and write below code:

```
CDate({Дата})>= {?Pm-@Required date}
and
CDate({Дата})< CDate(DateAdd("m",1,{?Pm-@Required date})
```

Now place the required fields on design of the report and run the report.

Let me know how it works